# Django social-auth: Fetching date of birth, address, and more fields from facebook

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using [django-social-auth](http://www.github.com/omab/django-social-auth) app for my social logging. Now I want to fetch more information from facebook like dob,address and many more. In this I tried using putting in settings
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS but it is not working for me.
Please help me in knowing, how to fetch more information using social auth from facebook, google and twitter

Thanks in advance

Paritosh

Comment: Can I just confirm, which Django social auth are you using? django-social-auth (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) or django-socialauth (https://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth). The latter seems to be rather unmaintained at the moment, whereas the former seems to be much more active.

Comment: first one, i.e. omab one is being used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the extended permissions with django-social-auth you need to add them to the request selecting permissions you want from [facebook permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). For example in your case, you probably want `user_about_me` or `user_birthday`.

```
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['user_about_me']
```

For example.